# Are "in end position" and "at the end" interchangeable both in writing and speaking?

Tags: meaning

This video (https://youtu.be/38-K2rPu8fc?t=167) is talking about the usage of "also" and gives this example

> She wrote three emails to him but he didn't answer, he ignored her calls as well.

[image]

The usage of "also" could be explained as,

> The "also" is put in the end of the sentence.

or

> The "also" is put in end position.

In term of the position of a component in a sentence, are "in end position" and "at the end" interchangeable ?

I found the speaker like using "in end position". I guess the reason is "at the end" sounds like "the end of a story", is it?

Generally, are "in end position" and "at the end" interchangeable both in writing and speaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker is Russian and has made a mistake in English and omitted the definite article. (from 07:10 in the video)

"in end position" is wrong, it should be "in **the** end position".

The phrase "in **the** end position" is grammatically correct but is very rarely used and would not be used in this context. (See [Link to Google Ngrams for "in the end position,at the end]"[1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20end%20position%2Cat%20the%20end&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20end%20position%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20end%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20end%20position%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20end%3B%2Cc0)))

In any case. "At the end" is far more common and sounds better.